# R line segment for Time Series Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a graph using ggplot2 in R and want to draw a line segment that's half the length between 2 points on the x-axis. The x-axis consists of dates and when I try to draw the segment it joins the 2 dates. How can I half the length and draw the line segment?

Sample Data:-

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjNQr.png)

[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEHBH.png)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of the data you are using, or even a mock dataframe?

Comment: Have you looked at the function ```geom_segment```?

Comment: @SebSta yes I have but it creates a segment that joins the 2 days and I want half of that.

Comment: @RobinTurkington the dataframe is basically just a bunch of dates and values:-

Comment: @Spaceguy152 please read the section on [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please don't just post screenshots of your data - use ``dput()`` to print out a sample of it.

Comment: @Spaceguy152 I would assume your x axis is of the class ```Date```. Im pretty sure your starting and endponts can only be actual date. Try changing the x-axis data to ```posixct``` and the axis itself to ```datetime```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the mtcars dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
sp <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
sp + geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 15, xend = 3, yend = 15))
```

Which would give you this:-

[image]

You can customise the length with `xend`, which specifies where you want the line to end. However, with dates I am not so sure. If I am right in saying with your example, are you trying to place that line between 2 "DateTimes"? If so, would it not be easier if you changed the Date format to DMY_HM? Because I think this would make it easier to specify the exact length of the line.